# Display records only if its belongs from table(1) in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

i have 2 tables which are join together with the help of UNION and display the records using single while loop.

problem:
now the problem is i want do display records from table(1) and table(2) separately but condition is using only single while loop.

here is the SQL:`

```
$sql =  "(SELECT * FROM subject_first WHERE date BETWEEN '$user_from' AND '$user_to') UNION (SELECT * FROM subject_second WHERE date BETWEEN '$user_from' AND '$user_to')";
```

is there any way to do it?.sorry to say but i am new to PHP.
any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a field to both sides of the query:

```
(SELECT *, 'subject_first' as `table` FROM subject_first WHERE date BETWEEN '$user_from' AND '$user_to') 
UNION 
(SELECT *, 'subject_second' as `table` FROM subject_second WHERE date BETWEEN '$user_from' AND '$user_to')
ORDER BY `table`
```

I added the order by part so you can insert a `<br>` or whatever to split the results.

Comment: sir i tried but it give an sql error:#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table FROM subject_first WHERE date BETWEEN '5-jun-2017' AND '8-jun-2017') UNI' at line 1

Comment: i just input directly the values 5-jun-2017 and 8-jun-2017'

Comment: Silly me, `table` is a registered keyword. Just updated the answer.

Comment: sir its working perfectly. you was such a genius thankyou